# HTML Web UI kit

Tags: html, user-interface

I have been browsing the web lately to find a good Web UI kit. I have found some very [good ones](http://www.designkindle.com/2011/05/09/black-ui-kit/) but they are all in PSD. That is, they are just graphics. I'm not a professional Photoshop user and it seems like the process to get the UI to HTML to work is quite long and painful.

So has anyone done it before? If not, what are the best resources to get me started to slicing a Web UI kit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development.

[MooTools](http://mootools.net/)  is a compact, modular, Object-Oriented JavaScript framework designed for the intermediate to advanced JavaScript developer. It allows you to write powerful, flexible, and cross-browser code with its elegant, well documented, and coherent API.

[Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) saves you time, delivers powerful performance, and scales with your development process. It’s the toolkit experienced developers turn to for building superior desktop and mobile web experiences.

[The YUI Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) is a set of utilities and controls, written with JavaScript and CSS, for building richly interactive web applications using techniques such as DOM scripting, DHTML and AJAX.